# How to make ng e2e run on available port?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

After upgrading to Angular 6, `ng e2e` doesn't run on available port.
For example, if you take the previous version of Angular (we were previously using 4), you will be having the app service in port number 4200 and when we simultaneously run `ng e2e`, it used to pick a free port (like 49152) to run tests.

After Angular 6 upgrade, when I try to run the tests on similar scenario, it fails with the error message "Port 4200 is already in use".

I don't want to manually pass `--port {port number}` to the command for CI purposes since hardcoding port numbers will have problems in parallel executions in CI. Something broke during the upgrade to Angular 6, should I change the configuration?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to find the solution for this.

Just run `ng e2e <app-name> --port 0` to run on available ports.

When this command executes, the tests will look for available ports in case of parallel execution. We don't need to explicitly hardcode or provide port numbers every time.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me in my issue.
I was getting this on running e2e:
"Port 8080 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port."

Comment: How does Protractor know the port? Is it possible to retrieve the chosen port? - I'm asking because I'm using cypress and I have this base URL incl. port number which I have to pass to Cypress, also I have a CORS thing which I need to solve by passing on this same port number

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. You could try something like this: In your `package.json` file, in `scripts` you can enter `"e2e": ng e2e --port number` from there, within the command line, you can enter `npm run e2e`.